# Luces en OpenGL

Tags: visual-studio, animación, opengl

Necesito que una luz (spotlight) se mueva cuando un auto se mueve. El código del modelo del auto es el siguiente:

```
model = glm::mat4(1.0);
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, mainWindow.getadelante())); //Para que el auto se mueva hacia adelante
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, mainWindow.getatras())); //Para que el auto se mueva hacia atras
modelaux = model; // Utilizado para jerarquia 
modelcar = modelaux; // Utilizado para jerarquia
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
kittobj_M.RenderModel();
```

Como ejemplo de la luz, tengo lo siguiente:

```
// luz tipo flash ligada a la cámara
glm::vec3 lowerLight = camera.getCameraPosition();
lowerLight.y -= 0.3f;
spotLights[0].SetFlash(lowerLight, camera.getCameraDirection());
```

Necesito hacer lo de la cámara con el auto, y por lo que entiendo es casi lo mismo, solo tengo que darle la dirección del auto (según yo) el problema es que no he encontrado la forma.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Qué necesitas hacer con la cámara si dices que quieres una luz que se mueva con el auto?

Comment: con la cámara no tengo que hacer nada, solo puse el código de la cámara como ejemplo